# Question about DBD::CSB Statement-Functions

Tags: sql, perl, function, csv, dbd

From the SQL::Statement::Functions documentation:

> Function syntax
>
> When using SQL::Statement/SQL::Parser directly to parse SQL, functions (either built-in or user-defined) may occur anywhere in a SQL statement that values, column names, table names, or predicates may occur. When using the modules through a DBD or in any other context in which the SQL is both parsed and executed, functions can occur in the same places except that they can not occur in the column selection clause of a SELECT statement that contains a FROM clause.
>
> # valid for both parsing and executing

```
 SELECT MyFunc(args);
 SELECT * FROM MyFunc(args);
 SELECT * FROM x WHERE MyFuncs(args);
 SELECT * FROM x WHERE y < MyFuncs(args);
```

> # valid only for parsing (won't work from a DBD)

```
 SELECT MyFunc(args) FROM x WHERE y;
```

Reading this I would expect that the first SELECT-statement of my example shouldn't work and the second should but it is quite the contrary.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings; use strict;
use 5.010;
use DBI;

open my $fh, '>', 'test.csv' or die $!;
say $fh "id,name";
say $fh "1,Brown";
say $fh "2,Smith";
say $fh "7,Smith";
say $fh "8,Green";
close $fh;

my $dbh = DBI->connect ( 'dbi:CSV:', undef, undef, {
    RaiseError => 1,
    f_ext      => '.csv',
    });

my $table = 'test';

say "\nSELECT 1";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare ( "SELECT MAX( id ) FROM $table WHERE name LIKE 'Smith'" );
$sth->execute ();
$sth->dump_results();

say "\nSELECT 2";
$sth = $dbh->prepare ( "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = MAX( id )" );
$sth->execute ();
$sth->dump_results();
```

outputs:

> SELECT 1
>   '7'
>   1 rows
>
> SELECT 2
>   Unknown function 'MAX' at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/SQL/Parser.pm line 2893.
>   DBD::CSV::db prepare failed: Unknown function 'MAX' at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/SQL/Parser.pm line 2894.
>    [for Statement "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = MAX( id )"] at ./so_3.pl line 30.
>   DBD::CSV::db prepare failed: Unknown function 'MAX' at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/SQL/Parser.pm line 2894.
>    [for Statement "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = MAX( id )"] at ./so_3.pl line 30.

Could someone explaine me this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

$sth = $dbh->prepare ( "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = 
                         (select MAX( id ) FROM $table)" );

Comment: When I try this I get this error-messages:
Bad table or column name: '(select MAX (id) FROM test)' has chars not alphanumeric or underscore! at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/SQL/Parser.pm line 2893.
DBD::CSV::db prepare failed: Bad table or column name: '(select MAX (id) FROM test)' has chars not alphanumeric or underscore! at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/SQL/Parser.pm line 2894.
 [for Statement "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = ( select MAX( id ) FROM test )"] at ./so_3.pl line 32.

Comment: @sid_com - Then first execute - select MAX( id ) FROM $table - put the result in a variable (say, $max_id) and execute the second query: 
SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = $max_id

Comment: Does that mean that "Select MAX(id) FROM $table WHERE id = $max_id" is OK? Concerns the "# valid only for parsing (won't work from a DBD) - SELECT MyFunc(args) FROM x WHERE y;" only user-defined functions?

Comment: I don't know. :-) I don't work with  DBD::CSB. I just noticed that 
SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = MAX( id )
is not correct from SQL point of view and suppose correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I saw something similar to this occur today. I found that if I did:

```
    my $foo = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table");
    if($foo) {
       $foo->finish();
    }
    #run your prepare here
```

directly before the query that used a UDF or function, the error went away...I went with it :)